# Why " allowSyntheticDefaultImports " and "esModuleInterop" do not work?

Tags: typescript

This is my file structure and `ts config`. I have set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports"`and `"esModuleInterop"` as true.

However, when I try to `import` from a `no-default` file. There will be a `no-default` error

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEOrB.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7wo0.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nxZp.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs0ZE.png
```